# android user interface, integrating button and edit text

Tags: android, user-interface, button, android-edittext

I am a beginner to android programming. 
So I am sorry if some of you find this trivial.
I want to implement a functionality where a button is not separate from edittext.
That is they have no physical distinction.

---

|          aa | 
|          aa |

---

In place of the a's there is the button. How do I implement this?

Comment: i meant a's in a right corner of a rectangular box. they dint quite come that way.

Comment: the rectangular box itself is the edittext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I could understand your question, you are trying to put buttons into an EditText. Is that right?

If yes, I'm afraid there could occur some problems concerning focus etc., so try to avoid layouts like this.

Have you tried RelativeLayout?

Comment: You are correct. Actually it is a contacts tab. So I want to be able to add users numbers if they are sending say a message to many recipients. I have not used RelativeLayout. If I use that I am afraid I'll type words right into the button.

Comment: I tried RelativeLayout. I tried to order it. But it is ignoring my layout_gravity which i kept for the button. Any other solutions?

Comment: huh, I´m sorry for this, but I haven´t already tried it.
Maybe you should consider putting both buttons into a LinearLayout and let it be as large as the EditText.
If this shouln´t work, could you post your xml-code here?